# How to get team name after record assigned in crm 2011 Plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

**Aim**: need to get team name after assigned Record.

**Description**: In contact Entity,I assign one Contact to team. The team name is "ABC".
                         I need to get that team name "ABC" in Plugin.The plugin was triggered After the record was assigned.Post-validation method.How can I get the  Assigned team Name?

Comment: on which message the plugin should trigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Plugin Message is **Assign**. You Can Use the below Code to get the **Assigned team Name**

```
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && 
context.InputParameters["Target"] is EntityReference)
{
EntityReference targetEntity = 
(EntityReference)context.InputParameters["Target"];

if (targetEntity.LogicalName != "contact")
{ return; }

if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Assignee"))
{
EntityReference assigneeRef =
(EntityReference)context.InputParameters["Assignee"];

if (assigneeRef.LogicalName == "team")
{
string assignName = assigneeRef.Name;//to retrieve assigned team name

}
}
}
```

Comment: I got null insteadof teamname

Comment: I got null insteadof teamname .I register the plugin like the following stage eventing stage pipe line as:Post-Operation.Execution mode:synchronous deployment:server

Comment: to retrieve team use service.retrieve method get column name

Comment: var retrieve = service.Retrieve(assigneeRef.LogicalName, assigneeRef.Id, new ColumnSet("name"));
                                            string getTeamName = Convert.ToString(retrieve.Attributes["name"]);

Comment: did you get that name?

Comment: @passion.Yeah ..Got the team name now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65564/discussion-between-passion-and-user).